# Adding a user control to a GridViewColumn

Tags: wpf, user-controls, gridviewcolumn

I'm trying to add a custom user control of mine to a GridViewColumn and all I get is the ToString() output of that control.

my code:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Progress" HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyHeaderStyle}">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ProgressBar, Converter={StaticResource nullGuestImageConverter}}" Width="150" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
```

I have tried before

```
<GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyHeaderStyle}"  Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ProgressBar}" />
```

to no avail.

please help

Comment: Have you specified in your Resources what type of data you want to implement?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You have to specify what `Type` of data you want to implement in your Resources otherwise WPF will automatically call .toString() on your data.